# How does PHP connection to firebase work?

Tags: php, firebase

If you have the time to read the [firebase-php](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php) documentation, you can see there how to use the helper library to "connect" to *firebase*. But unfortunately, I think that the connection could only be established by phpunit, in other words, output can only be seen in the terminal. Since when you run the php pages in your browser, it will *return fatal errors*. Does anyone know how to use the **helper library** to connect to the *firebase* data without using *phpunit*? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For anyone reading this important old QA, note that this library is somewhat deprecated stackoverflow.com/a/48968449/294884

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using the lib is very easy, when you just look at the source code of the tests.

There are two kinds of tests:

- [a real functionality test](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php/blob/master/tests/firebaseTest.php), which uses cURL requests to the server and therefore is slow during testing with PHPUnit
- [a mocked functionality test (stub)](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php/blob/master/tests/firebaseStubTest.php), which simulates the connection to and the response from the server, which is faster during testing

Now, in order to use firebase-php, you would simply do the same things as in the real functionality test. Include the lib, prepare the connection object with login credentials and then call the method you want. The [interface](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php/blob/master/src/firebaseInterface.php) describes, which methods you can expect in the firebaseLib class -
or just look at the [lib source itself](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php/blob/master/src/firebaseLib.php).

This piece of code should get you started:

```
require '/path/to/libs/firebase-php/firebaseLib.php';
$url = '...';
$token = '...';
$firebase = new Firebase($url, $token);
$firebase->get('something/from/somewhere');
```

---

If you fetch the library via `composer`, you might declare an autoloading classmap, too. The author hasn't done this, yet.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["vendor/ktamas77/firebase-php/firebaseLib.php"]
    }
}
```

Then simply require Composer's Autoloader with `require "vendor/autoload.php";` and `new Firebase` to autoload the class.

---

**How to get the auth token**

- open your firebase console
- go to project settings
- go to the database
- then copy the secret key

[image: get-firebase-token]

Comment: This worked! Thank you! But may I know why the firebaseLib.php is the only file required in the project? Thanks!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. Why only one file? The interface dependency is required inside the firebaseLib directly at the top. If the project would be comperser-ified correctly this file would also be autoloaded. All other files are stubs or test files, which would go into Composers "autoload-dev" section, because they are only required during testing and not during production. In order to interact with the FirebaseAPI you only need cURL access to the service, a JSON encoding/decoding helper and accessor methods: it's simple, that's why it's only one file.

Comment: How to get $token

Comment: I've updated my answer and added the steps to get the token.

Comment: For anyone reading this important QA 2018, note that this library is somewhat deprecated https://stackoverflow.com/a/48968449/294884