# Login/Auth with PHP and FireBase

Tags: php, mysql, firebase

first hand i want to say thanks for any help you can give me, im working on a small project where the idea is to create a login for the user, where after login, the user going to be able to see his photo from his account, now, Initialy the data base was mysql, but now it was changed to firebase and i dont have any idea how to make the connection between php and firebase, if someone can help me i really appreciate it.

Best Regards.

Comment: Firebase client : -> https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php or SDK -> https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php

Comment: Here is the answer to you question [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293038/how-does-php-connection-to-firebase-work)

Comment: You may also check https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php

Comment: Thanks you so much guys really helpfull :D