# Can we use Firebase Realtime database with core PHP?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Android app and backend code is in core PHP using MySql.

Is there any way to perform CRUD operations from API directly the way we perform on MySql?

if it was a web app, it could be done it using javascript, but can we directly from API? Or... Doing it from the Android end would is the last option.

Comment: I respect everyone's opinion, but if you could leave a comment before you down-vote it would help.. Thanks in Advance...

Comment: @Sachith thanks for your suggestion, and I have tried things and mentioned it in the description and the question was a new thing which I don't know if that's possible or not and if yes then how and I didn't knew how to try that

Comment: You better to include you tried codes, errors to the question.

Comment: This is an excellent question - thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To work with Firebase from an Android device, you should definitely use the official Android SDK https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

If you want to execute administrative tasks from a privileged server in PHP, I think you should have a look at https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php - here's a usage example:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

// This assumes that you have placed the Firebase credentials in the same directory
// as this PHP file.
$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/google-service-account.json');

$firebase = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
    ->create();

$database = $firebase->getDatabase();

$newPost = $database
    ->getReference('blog/posts')
    ->push([
        'title' => 'Post title',
        'body' => 'This should probably be longer.'
    ]);

$newPost->getChild('title')->set('Changed post title');
$newPost->getValue(); // Fetches the data from the realtime database
$newPost->remove();
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the library :)

Comment: @jeromegamez, I guess, your awesome library is much more up to date than stackoverflow.com/a/28293540/294884 ?

Comment: @Fattie Yes it is ^^. As soon as Firebase removes support for database secrets (which they have deprecated a long time ago), the ktamas77/firebase-php will unfortunately stop working.

Comment: @Fattie Did you just put a bounty on this question? If so, why? It's so old already 

Comment: Fantastic.  I added a large bounty to this critical question.  I guess firebase mention on their doco: your library, and one by talmasKalman.  Yours is better right?

Comment: (I always add bounties on important questions, new or old !)

Comment: @Fattie I have difficulties to say point-blank that my library is *better* - the ktamas/firebase-php library allows interacting with the Firebase Realtime Database with very low effort and restrictions - with it, you can write and read from the Database in basically just one line `(new \Firebase\FirebaseLib($url, $dbSecret))->set($key, $value);`. On the other hand the kreait library supports more Firebase services and is actively maintained, but also is heavier in size. I'd still recommend using my library - of course :D

Comment: @Fattie Thank YOU!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in PHP google app standard environment engine, has anyone else experienced a similar issue?

Comment: @Hews On GCP/GCE you can use the ServiceAccount Autodiscovery (see https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup.html#with-autodiscovery), which uses https://github.com/kreait/gcp-metadata-php under the hood.

Comment: @jeromegamez thanks for your help! To confirm, in my .yaml file I set up the environment-variable to the filepath for the json file. Is that sufficient? I'm not sure if it meets the criteria for "google's well known path". Thanks

Comment: @Hews On Google Platforms you don’t need a service account at all. You should be good with a `$firebase = (new Factory())->create();`

Comment: you are awesome.